# How to switch to div in selenium web driver if Frame is not available

Tags: java, selenium

```
<div class="panel panel-default ng-scope" ng-repeat="leftNavParent in
 leftNavCtrl.displayedNavItems">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a ng-if="leftNavParent.ChildNavigationLinks.length > 0" 
              href="#!" class="activeContent ng-binding ng-scope" ng-
              click="leftNavCtrl.leftNavHeaderClicked(leftNavParent)">
                Modules
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
     <div class="panel-collapse collapse in slide" ng-
      show="leftNavParent.Expand" style="display: block;">
       <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="childNavParent in 
                 leftNavParent.ChildNavigationLinks" class="list-group-item 
                 ng-scope" ng-class="{'active' : 
                 leftNavCtrl.selectedNavItemId == childNavParent.Id}">
                    <a class="inboxsublink ng-binding" ui-sref-opts="
                      {reload: true}" ui-sref="AAA({ action: 'AAADashBoard', 
                       role: '18'})" href="18">Interactions
                       <span ng-if="childNavParent.HasCount" class="badge 
                         red-background pull-right ng-scope">
                            <span ng-if="childNavParent.Count >= 0" 
                             class="ng-binding ng-scope" style="">0</span>
                         </span>
                     </a>
                    <ul class="list-group sub_list slide ng-scope ng-hide" 
                    ng-if="childNavParent.ChildNavigationLinks.length > 0" 
                    ng-show="childNavParent.Expand" style="display: none;">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-sub ng-
                            scope" ng-repeat="childNavParentChild in 
                            childNavParent.ChildNavigationLinks" ng-class="
                            {'active' : leftNavCtrl.selectedNavItemId == 
                            childNavParentChild.Id}" style="">
                            <a class="inboxsublink ng-binding" ui-sref-
                            opts="{reload: true}" ui-sref="AAA({ action: 
                            'DashBoard', role: '19' })" href="19">
                                Administrator
                            </a>           
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//Here I changed my code actual one. The element I wanted to select Modules and when I click the module there will be sub menu getting opened. This actually a Menu on right hand side. I think its dynamically getting generated

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve], show what you have tried so far. Also your problem description is not clear enough, explain it in more detail. Give some examples. And use the formatting options of the SO editor, also indent your code and HTML to show the structure.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared your requirement of *how to find element* **class="Activity-link cmm_action_link btn btn-primary"** matches exactly with two nodes/webelements as follows :

- First :

  ```
  <a class="Activity-link cmm_action_link btn btn-primary" ui-sref="SearchCMM({action: 'Search', pDashboardName: 'IHCP'})" href="/SearchMM-Search-">Search Records</a>
  ```
- Second :

  ```
  <a class="Activity-link cmm_action_link btn btn-primary" ui-sref="CMMRecordManagement({action: 'CreateRecord', pDashboardName: 'IHCP'})" href="/CMM">Create New Record</a>
  ```

However to click on the above mentioned links you can use the following lines of code :

- *Search Records* :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Search Records")).click();
  //or
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='Activity-link cmm_action_link btn btn-primary' and @href='/SearchMM-Search-']")).click();
  ```
- *Create New Record* :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create New Record")).click();
  //or
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='Activity-link cmm_action_link btn btn-primary' and @href='/CMM']")).click();
  ```

Comment: It is giving me an error that webdriver is unable to find the element

Comment: @user9370262 Can you update the question with the entire error stack trace for further analysis?

Comment: Can some one help me please